# Angular js row update

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I have a list of servers and their status to show in a table, which come from ws response. Currently I have showed them using factories. But for status, I have to run another ws for each server to get the status with `$interval`. this causes rows are being displayed slowly, after they get the server status.

here's my code:

```
ServerService.getServers().then(
      function(result) {
        var tempServers = [];
        $scope.totalServers = result.data.length;
        angular.forEach(result.data, function(server){
          ServerService.getStatus(server.id).then(
            function(result) {
              server.status = result.data;
              tempServers.push(server);
              $scope.servers = tempServers;
            },
            function(rejected) {
              console.log(rejected);
            }
          );

        });
      },
      function(rejected) {
        console.log(rejected);
      }
    );
```

Is there any faster way, so that I can show the server list quickly, and then fetch status of them and update each row separately?

Please help. I'm new in angular js

Answer (score 0):

I've used socket.io finally to get status of servers. It results faster response.